# No up or down arrows on vertical scrollbar with Libreoffice write in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: libreoffice, 18.04, scrollbar

I'm trying to work on a document in Libreoffice and there are no up or down arrows in the vertical scroll sidebar.  This makes it hard to move up or down in the document.  How do I get the up and down arrows in the scroll sidebar?

15.04 fixes doesn't work with 18.04

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/705314/scroll-bar-arrows-missing-after-a-recent-update-of-15-10

Comment: Essentially, you can search for a gtk3 theme that has the little arrows present by default, or, if possible, edit your theme's existing `gtk-widgets.css` to change     `-GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: false;` and `-GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: false;` to `true`

Comment: Didn't help.  Older version, not 18.04

Comment: Also can't use GTK themes in 18.04 at this point.

Comment: As a short term fix, you can grab the scroll bar slider and move it up and down. For smaller movements use PageUp and PageDown keys.

Comment: Using the up and down keys doesn't work the same.  It is frustrating.

Comment: also with long documents, using the scroll bar slide doesn't work well either.

Comment: Unfortunately developers of GNOME are completely ignoring usability and long standing GUI conventions in the sake of "modernizing" their interface! :( I tried all the default desktop managers and all the themes installed by default in Ubuntu 19.04: All have the same problem of not displaying the arrows on the scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem ba uninstalling libreoffice-gtk2 and libreoffice-gtk3. To test it You can use "SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gen libreoffice " in a terminal window.